# ¿Cómo hacer un if según 3 veces cliqueado un botón?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo hacer un `if/else`, según **cada 3 veces** que se apriete un botón con cierta `ID`? ¿Y cómo hacer que cada una de las veces me muestre un alert?

Mi intento:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="play"onclick="start()"type="button" value="Jugar">
<input id="replay"type="button" value="volver a jugar">
<script>
function start(){
    var i = 0;
    var b = "";

    window.addEventListener("load", each3);

    function each3() {
        b = document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", contador);


        function contador() {
            i = i + 1;
        }

        if (i == 3) {
            alert('yay!');
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Deseo solamente una solución en JavaScript.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que salte un mensaje la tercera vez que se haga click sobre el botón play?

Comment: cada 3 veces que se haga click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para realizar una acción cada 3 veces que se pulse un botón no tienes más que crearte un contador e ir actualizándolo en el evento click.

Mira este ejemplo:

```js
(function(){
  var contador = 0;
  
  document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click',
    function(){
      if (contador === 2){
        alert('Tercera vez que se pulsa el botón');
        contador = 0;
      }
      else{
        contador++;
      }
    });
})();
```

```html
<input id="play" type="button" value="Jugar">
```

Comment: wow, la función anónima como sabe las veces que se ha dado click , si antes no has sumado en un contador?

Comment: jeje, ya entendí gracias asier!!!

Answer (score 0):

La solución de [Asier Villanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/72315/35436) es la óptima, pero yo he intentado moldear tu código y hacerlo como tú quieres:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="play"onclick="start()"type="button" value="Jugar">
<input id="replay"type="button" value="volver a jugar">
<script>
function start(){

 i = 0;
 b = "";

document.getElementById("play").removeAttribute("onclick");
document.getElementById("play").setAttribute("onclick","contador()");
}

function contador() {

i = i + 1;

if (i == 3) {

alert('yay!');
}

}

</script>
</body>
</html>









</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: está algo bug, pero gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

He estado un momento intentando leer tu código y debo admitirlo, me resultó un poco ambiguo, porque hay como unas funciones muy simples y mucho espacio en blanco. Voy a ver si he entendido lo que quieres lograr.

Por lo que entiendo de tu enunciado, quieres que **cada 3 veces** que hagas click en un botón tome cierta acción, que en este caso es un **alert()**.

Tienes tres funciones escritas pero solo te bastaría una para conseguir lo que tu quieres lograr, esto se podría llamar ***refactorización*** en este caso, porque estamos simplificando nuestro código para obtener las mismas funcionalidades que teníamos antes con un menor coste de recursos.

**1 -** Antes que nada, comentarte que el objeto ***window*** dispone de un método llamado ***onLoad()***, el cual lo que suceda dentro de su bloque de código, lo hará después de cargar la estructura de tu ***DOM***. Así podemos deshacernos de ese primer **Listener** que tienes para cargar, se quedaría así:

```
window.onload = loadEvents; // Cabe destacar que no hace falta declararla con () 

function loadEvents() {
   // Accion a realizar al cargar el DOM
   var contador = 0; //Nuestra variable que recogerá los clicks del botón.
   playButton = document.getElementById('play');
   // Guardamos nuestro botón en una variable para acceder a ella.
}
```

2 - Vale, con nuestra función de carga escrita y conseguido acceder a nuestro botón, podemos disponernos a conseguir la interacción con ese botón:

```
function loadEvents() {
   var contador = 0;
   playButton = document.getElementById('play');
   //Se puede añadir el Listener a la variable para mejor legibilidad.
   playButton.addEventListener('click', cuentaClicks, false);

}
```

3 - Nuestra función ***cuentaClicks*** esta declarada en el ***Listener*** pero no codificada, así que vamos a ello:

```
function cuentaClicks() {

   if (contador < 3) {
     contador++; // Esto es similar a => contador = contador + 1
    } else {
        alert('yai!'); //Después de tres clicks se muestra nuestro alert()
        contador = 0; // Reiniciamos el contador para usarlo de nuevo.
    }
}
```

4 - Nuestro código final quedaría así:

```
<script>
 window.onload = loadEvents;

  function loadEvents() {

   var contador = 0; // Variable global que utilizaremos de contador

   playButton = document.getElementById('play');
   //Se puede añadir el Listener a la variable para mejor legibilidad.
   playButton.addEventListener('click', cuentaClicks, false);

}

function cuentaClicks() {

   if (contador < 3) {
     contador++; // Esto es similar a => contador = contador + 1
   } else {
        alert('yai!'); //Después de tres clicks se muestra nuestro alert()
        contador = 0; // Reiniciamos el contador para usarlo de nuevo.
    }
}

</script>
```

5 - ¡Un saludo! y espero que respondas si te ha funcionado o no :)

Comment: Creo que lo que haces en else se debe hacer en if y viceversa